# how to override jquery.yiigridview.js in yiiframework

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, yii, overriding

file location is: [yiiroot/framework/widjets/assets/gridview/jquery.yiigridview.js](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/zii/widgets/assets/gridview/jquery.yiigridview.js)
I need to change one line in this file so that I can use it in my requirements.

```
//original code line 79,80
                if (settings.ajaxUpdate.length > 0) {
                    $(document).on('click.yiiGridView', settings.updateSelector, function () {

//I need to change it to :

                if (settings.ajaxUpdate.length > 0) {
                    $(this).parent().on('click.yiiGridView', settings.updateSelector, function () {
```

what is the right way to override this without needing to change the source code file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternate method to do this would be to use [jQuery's `off` method](http://api.jquery.com/off/).

Using `off` you can remove the event handler that is already added in *jquery.yiigridview.js*, and then add a new handler using `on`.

Something like this(in the view that has the grid view):

```
<?php
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('myownhandlers',
    "
        $(document).off('click.yiiGridView', $.fn.yiiGridView.settings['your-grid-id'].updateSelector); // this will remove the jquery.yiigridview.js handler

        // assign the new handler, instead of $(this) you have to use the id of the element you are interested in
        $('#the-id-you-are-interested-in').parent().on('click.yiiGridView', settings.updateSelector, function () {
        // your function's code, you'll have to write your function
        });
    ",
    CClientScript::POS_LOAD // this is important because the default is POS_READY, and the gridview is available only after load
);
?>
```

Read on about [the `on` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) too to get a better understanding of the code.

**Note:**

Take care that the event namespace i.e `click.yiiGridView` is correct, actually in the version of yii i have there is no namespace and it is just `click`, so check that before overriding.

Comment: btw, is this in any way related to your [other question about nested grids](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284068/yii-cgridview-ajaxupdate-property)? will this solve that problem?

Comment: Please remove "->" after registerScript :)

Answer (score 2):

Copy the entire contents of the folder `yiiroot/framework/zii/widgets/assets/gridview/` to a location accessible by the client, say `your_web_app_dir/gridview` and make the modifications you want. Then add the `baseScriptUrl` attribute in the gridview and set it it to the path to your modified files folder  as shown below

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'model-grid',
    'baseScriptUrl'=>Yii::app()->baseUrl.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'gridview',
    'dataProvider'=>$datatProvider,
    'columns'=>array(
     ....
     ....
     ),
    )); ?>
```

Comment: thank you, I hoped that there is a way to use some jquery code to override the only line that I need to change.