# How do I use the ajaxUrl parameter of CGridView in Yii?

Tags: ajax, yii

I'm trying to use ajaxUrl param of CGridView and it's having no effect.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
   'id'=>'ge-cg-'.$myLib['id'],
   'filter'=>$geCGModel,
   'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider, 
   'columns'=>$columns,
   'ajaxUrl'=>Yii::app()->createUrl( 'Something/search' ),
));
```

This doesn't seem to be overriding the ajax url of the CGridView widget. The grid's ajax request is still going to the controller that rendered it (which is different than the grid's own controller).

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `ajaxUrl` property works only for searches, both the "per column filters" and "advanced search". The sort links and pagination links are generated from the `$dataProvider` that you specify. You can check the source of CGridView and CDataColumn to see how [pagination](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/zii/widgets/grid/CGridView.php#L394) and [sorting](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/zii/widgets/grid/CDataColumn.php#L110) is extracted from the dataProvider, respectively.

Hence if you want those links to also use the same `ajaxUrl` that you want to specify, then you have to set the `route` property for both the CPagination object, and CSort object of the `$dataProvider`, somewhat like this:

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Modelname',array(
    'criteria'=>$criteria,
    'pagination'=>array(
        'route'=>'something/search'
    ),
    'sort'=>array(
        'route'=>'something/search'
    )
));
```

This combined with your current CGridView settings should work as expected.

Comment: i hope i got you correctly, but looking at your url again, it seems that you want search to work with that ajaxurl (not just pagination and sort). Search should work without making the changes i mentioned in the answer, so if your search is not working let me know.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. I ended up working around it by making a secondary ajax request which defaulted everything to the correct url, but this should be useful in the future.

Comment: Glad to help, but i'm just curious, was your search working with that ajaxUrl? if not can you tell me if that was your entire configuration for the gridview(minus the columns)? or you had some other properties also defined? also let me know your yii version.

Comment: Yes, it was working. I didn't realize the search url was set, but the sort and page wasn't.  I figured all 3 would be set by ajaxUrl.