# Pagination not working in Yii Framework

Tags: php, yii, pagination, yii-extensions

I am using Yii Rights modules for ACL where I want pagination for Permissions page.

Following is my code:

In `AuthItemController.php`

```
public function actionPermissions() {
        $dataProvider = new RPermissionDataProvider('permissions', array(
                    'pagination' => array(
                        'pageSize' => 10,
                        //'class' => 'CPagination', //showing an error
                        'itemCount' => 32
                        )));

        // Get the roles from the data provider
        $roles = $dataProvider->getRoles();
        $roleColumnWidth = $roles !== array() ? 75 / count($roles) : 0;

        // Initialize the columns
        $columns = array(
            array(
                'name' => 'description',
                'header' => Rights::t('core', 'Item'),
                'type' => 'raw',
                'htmlOptions' => array(
                    'class' => 'permission-column',
                    'style' => 'width:25%',
                ),
            ),
        );

        // Add a column for each role
        foreach ($roles as $roleName => $role) {
            $columns[] = array(
                'name' => strtolower($roleName),
                'header' => $role->getNameText(),
                'type' => 'raw',
                'htmlOptions' => array(
                    'class' => 'role-column',
                    'style' => 'width:' . $roleColumnWidth . '%',
                ),
            );
        }

        $view = 'permissions';
        $params = array(
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'columns' => $columns,
        );

        // Render the view
        isset($_POST['ajax']) === true ? $this->renderPartial($view, $params) : $this->render($view, $params);
    }
```

And in `View`

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
        'type' => 'bordered',
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'template' => '{pager}{items}',
        'emptyText' => Rights::t('core', 'No authorization items found.'),
        'htmlOptions' => array('class' => 'grid-view permission-table'),
        'columns' => $columns,
        'pager' => array(
            'header' => '',
            'hiddenPageCssClass' => 'disabled',
            'maxButtonCount' => 3,
            'cssFile' => false,
            'class' => 'CLinkPager',
            'prevPageLabel' => '<i class="icon-chevron-left"></i>',
            'nextPageLabel' => '<i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>',
            'firstPageLabel' => 'First',
            'lastPageLabel' => 'Last',
        ),
        'pagerCssClass' => 'pagination',
    ));
```

I have already implemented pagination for other pages by using same method but here in rights module its not working. Its not showing any error but also not displaying pagination links/buttons.

Comment: I don't know `RPermissionDataProvider`, but may be the `totalItemCount` attribute of the data provider is missing? For example if it extends `CSqlDataProvider` it will be needed. From yii doc => Note: if you want to use the pagination feature, you must configure the totalItemCount property to be the total number of rows (without pagination). And if you want to use the sorting feature, you must configure sort property so that the provider knows which columns can be sorted.

Comment: And you're sure there are more than 10 items?

Comment: @davey : Yes there are more than 10 items

Comment: @darkheir `RPermissionDataProvider` inherits from `CDataProvider` but it has `calculateTotalItemCount` so should paginate.

Comment: @PeterM: I also tried by extending `CActiveDataProvider` but still its not working. In rights module do they have any provision for pagination or not?

Comment: RPermissionDataProvider extends CDataProvider, which has the pagination property, so it should work like this. Did you check the pagination isn't somehow hidden with javascript and/or css?

Comment: @davey: No there is not any issue of JS/CSS. Actually I have created pagination for couple of modules and all are working perfectly except this YiiRights module.

Comment: Very strange, try to set the class explicitly and itemCount manually to something > 10: 

'pagination' => array(
                'class' => 'CPagination',
                'pageSize' => 10,
                'itemCount' => 32
)

Comment: @davey : Where? In widget or in controller?

Comment: In your controller, $dateProvider = ....

Comment: @davey: When I am adding it to dataprovider its showing error : `CException

Property "CPagination.class" is not defined.

C:\wamp\www\yiiboilerplate\common\lib\Yii\web\CDataProvider.php(91)`

Comment: @davey : I have edited my post pleaase check

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37585/discussion-between-sky-and-davey)

Comment: @davey: I removed the `"class"=>"CPagination"` and now its showing pagination buttons and links there so one thing is done. But the functionality still not working means its showing all records on page and when I am clicking on paginations buttons/links its does nothing. Please let me know where I am going wrong now. Thanks

Comment: @PeterM: I removed the "class"=>"CPagination" and now its showing pagination buttons and links there so one thing is done. But the functionality still not working means its showing all records on page and when I am clicking on paginations buttons/links its does nothing. Please let me know where I am going wrong now

Comment: @darkheir: I removed the "class"=>"CPagination" and now its showing pagination buttons and links there so one thing is done. But the functionality still not working means its showing all records on page and when I am clicking on paginations buttons/links its does nothing. Please let me know where I am going wrong now. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when implementing multiple grids in one page, the solution that worked for me was , I checked the url the grid ajax call,and before update I manipulated the url, and set the correct url and parameters before ajax request!

like:

```
$this->widget('zii.grid.GridView', array(
  'id' => 'group-grid-customers-list-not-scheduled',
  'dataProvider' => $notScheduledVisitedDataProvider ,
  'beforeAjaxUpdate' => '
        function(id , options)
        { 
            options.url = options.url.split("&test=test&");
            options.url = options.url[0] + "&test=test&" + $(".search-form form").serialize(); 
        }',
  'columns' => array(
      'col1',
      'col2',
      'col3',
  ),
));
```

Comment: did you make a function for beforAjaxUpdate? can you share it? and also check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626622/how-do-i-use-the-ajaxurl-parameter-of-cgridview-in-yii